# How do I install gtk-fortran on windows 8?

Tags: windows, cmake, fortran, gtk3, gfortran

I want to build a GUI for some fortran code I have. GTK-Fortran seemed like a simple option, but I'm having trouble getting everything installed in the correct place.

I am using Windows 8. I have gfortran (version 4.8.1), Cmake, and GTK+ 3 installed. As far as I can tell, the last thing I need to do is include GTK-Fortran, which I download from https://github.com/jerryd/gtk-fortran (the link to download the .zip file is on the right side of the page), but all of the instructions on what to do with it are incredibly vague to me. The INSTALL instructions seem to want me to make a new directory, C:\build, and then do something with cmake, but I'm not sure what that something is or how to do it.

I have GTK+ 3 in C:\GTK, and its bin is included in the path. I would like to just put the GTK-Fortran files within the GTK folder, but I don't think that will actually give me access to the GTK-Fortran files.

Could someone give me very clear instructions on what to do with the files for GTK-Fortran so that I can call them from my own fortran code?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for using gtk-fortran under Windows is to install MSYS2/MINGW64, following the installation steps described in the wiki of the project:
https://github.com/vmagnin/gtk-fortran/wiki#windows